# laravel 5.2 pass id with onclick not working on delete()

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, onclick

Why i can not passing data with id,when i execute the code just null on delete()
I missed something help me :( 
This is my dataController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\topic; //use model topic
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Yajra\Datatables\Datatables; //datatable
use App\Http\Requests;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class dataController extends Controller
{
    public function listPerintah($list,Request $request)
    {
        switch ($list) {
            case 'delete':
                $id = $request['id'];
                $topic = topic::find($id);
                $topic->delete();
                return $topic->name.'Berhasil Dihapus'; 
                break;

            default:
                return view('datatable.index');
                break;
        }
    }

    //dataTable
    public function listData(Request $request)
    {   
        $table = topic::select(['topics.*', 'users.name as user_name'])
            ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'topics.user_id')
            ->get();

        $datatables = Datatables::of($table);
        if($keyword = $request->get('search')['value'])
        {
            $datatables->filterColumn('rownum', 'whereRaw', '@rownum + 1 like ?', ["%{$keyword}%"]);
        }
        return $datatables
                ->editColumn('user_name', function($table) {
                    return 'Oleh: '. $table->user_name;
                })
                ->editColumn('created_at', function($table) {
                    return Carbon::parse($table->created_at)->format('d F Y H:i:s');
                })
                ->addColumn('action',function($table){
                    return
                    '<a title="hapus" href="javascript:" onclick="deleteBtn('.$table->id.',\''.$table->title.'\')" class="btn btn-fill btn-xs btn-danger"><span class="fa fa-remove"></span></a>
                    <a title="ubah" href="'.url("datatable/edit?id=".$table->id).'"  
                    class="btn btn-xs btn-primary"><span class="fa fa-pencil"></span>
                    </a>' ;
                })
                ->make(true);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to get request data using `$request->input('id');` instead of `$request['id']`

`$request->all()` this used to get all passed input

If you want to get the id from parameter

like delete/{id} use can get the id from the function parameter

```
class dataController extends Controller
{
    public function listPerintah($list,Request $request,$id)
```